# Whisper Open Ai Got Stuck

Tags: openai-whisper

```
import whisper
import os
model = whisper.load_model("medium")
print("Sarted")
result = model.transcribe(os.path.join("samples","speech.mp3"),fp16=False)
print(result["text"])
```

You can find your API key on https://replicate.com
(Whisper_api) prasun@prasun-Latitude-5400:~/Documents/Projects/whisper-main$ python3 Api.py
Sarted

Getting stuck with no output

Comment: It depends on your hardware capabilities. It does seem stuck but for me it works real slow. Maybe you can wait. It took me 4 hours for a 20mins video.